# What is the value of a <div> wrapping the entire body?

Tags: html, css

I'm taking over website maintenance for a utility company.  The previous developer used far more `<div>`s than I would.  Most make sense to me, but I'm puzzling over this one:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <!-- All of the page content - header, footer, whatever -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything in the `<body>` tag is surrounded by an additional named `<div>`.  There's nothing before it or after it.

Is there a benefit to having a `<div>` there?  My understanding is that all styling could be applied directly to `<body>` with the same effect.  Even JavaScript could do identical things if I just declared `<body id="wrapper">`, couldn't it?

Comment: If he wanted the content to have a different background than the body...

Comment: `#wrapper` is fairly standard.

Comment: i use a wrapper whenever i want to apply an animation to the whole page (like sliding in/out) i just dont like touching the body element.

Comment: Thank you. This has been extremely helpful - I hadn't considered either the background color (we have a background image) or an intent to do animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually used for the sake of styling, e.g.,

```
body{
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#wrapper{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The above is for a simple ~10% left and right white border on the page.

---

Although slightly OT, there is no HTML5 element for this. I have seen `<main>` used in its place, however, quoting from [the MDN article for `<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main):

> The main content area consists of content that is directly related to,
>   or expands upon the central topic of a document or the central
>   functionality of an application. This content should be unique to the
>   document, excluding any content that is repeated across a set of
>   documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information,
>   site logos